# Why can't I set the value of a property to be the items argument of the readWithCompletion completion block?

Tags: ios, azure, objective-c-blocks, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I've just started to develop apps for the iOS platform and I'm using Azure's web services to access a remote database. I've been calling the `readWithCompletion:` method on the table to try and read all of the data in my database from the server.

In the completion block of the method call, I've logged the `items` argument to the console and my data is coming down successfully. I've tried this `NSMutableArray *stops = [items mutableCopy]` to get my data outside of the completion block but `stops` is nil once it's outside of the scope of the completion block.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
[self.table readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
    self.stops = [items mutableCopy];
}];
```

Comment: Sounds as if readWithCompletion is an asynchronous method, hence your block would be called after the embedded method is already out of scope. Whatever you need after that block is executed could be nicely wrapped into a new method that is called right from that block.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Is the `stops` property declared as `strong` or `retain`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the block is running asynchronously, which is what you'd expect for web request, then variables which are changed in the block won't be changed until the block executes, which will happen later, after the request completes.

Here's some abstract code, and the log results you should expect.  Let's say you have a table view whose model is an array of objects, and let's say the asynchronous request fetches those objects from a web service:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet *tableview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *model;

[webRequest performRequest:^(NSArray *result) {
    // this code runs later, when the request completes
    self.model = result;
    // update our UI to indicate that we fetched some data
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}];

// this code runs right away, so self.model is uninitialized at this point
// this is where we should update our UI to say that we are busy fetching data
```

Comment: well, technically, this won't compile since you cannot assign to a captured non-`__block` variable inside a block

Comment: "abstract code".  it's not meant to compile.  it's meant to illustrate a point about asynch.  but, i'll fix anyway....

Comment: @danh I've been messing around with my code and the block is running asynchronously as you have suggested, as it's a completion block that runs once the web request has completed. How can I update a UITableView with the data that I'm getting back once it has been retrieved?

Comment: @MartinTracey - I changed the example in my answer to better match a UI with a table view in it.

Comment: @danh It turns out that [self.tableView reloadData] was the magic method that I was looking for! I hadn't been calling that which was why my tableView was not reloading its data. Thanks so much for your help, though. I finally have my head around how asynchronous blocks work.